# Selenium Couldn't identify App crashes Android

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, appium, exception

Sometimes app crashes. But Selenium can only handle "noSuchElementException" or "TimeOutException". Does Appium runs a listener or something which tracks if the app is crashed? I really need the internal exception handling with selenium, like: "Object Not set to an instance of object" exception and such things. Is there a way to listen Android internal exceptions?
if there is not a way to do that, what is the way to do it? I do it with finding the  stopped" text. but I don't think it is the right way to handle app crash. Becasue sometimes app crashes but not shows the app stopped dialog, It just come back to main screen of Android.

P.S: I understand the concept of "TakesScreenshot" interface  when test failed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to listen Android internal exceptions?

If you use [Appium Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop#the-server-console-output-window) instead of the [NPM](https://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started) version, then you can see the output in the window.

Comment: can you say the way to handle this from code ?

Comment: want to discuss it with you on Linkedin if you have little time.

Comment: if you have sometime please let me discuss with you: https://www.linkedin.com/in/rashad-nasirli/